# Spring Boot Maven - Include native library

Tags: spring, maven

In my project i'm using `Sigar` library that require some native library. I would like to include all the files (.ddl, .so etc - that are platform specific) inside the JAR or, in the same directory where the jar will be run.

`Sigar` search those library in the java.library path, but i cant include all of them in the system `PATH` (my application will be executed in some production machines, and i can't touch the `PATH`).

In order to do this, i've this build phase in my `pom.xml`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                <workingDirectory>target</workingDirectory>
                <argLine>-Djava.library.path=${baseDir}/src/main/resources/lib</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When i run the `pack` goal (that is included in `spring-boot-maven-plugin`) and i run the jar (with `java -jar myJar.jar`) i got this error:

> Unable to open nested entry 'lib/libsigar-amd64-freebsd-6.so'. It has
>   been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without
>   compression. Please check the mechanism used to create your executable
>   jar file

Someone can tell me how i can build this JAR ? I've just used spring-boot-maven-plugin because is included in Spring Boot Starter project.