# Load dll in spring boot executable jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am trying to load the dll in spring boot application converted to an executable jar. It works fine in intellij ide but it doesn't work in when i run as a jar. Any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: Would you provide how has to be done.  I add the libs in boot-int/classes/lib and I am using System.LoadLibrary("dll_name")

Comment: Similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663328/spring-boot-maven-include-native-library